# Shopify Website crashing only on Mobile Safari on iOS 16.5

Tags: ios, safari, shopify

I'm getting the "A Problem Repeatedly Occurred" error on my website all of a sudden.

The error only happens on Safari on iOS 16.5, It doesn't occur on previous versions of Safari.

The Error only happens on our collection pages and it only happens after you visit the page, go to another page and then return to the original collection page. All other pages (Home, Products, Regular pages etc) are working fine.

Web inspector isn't giving me any errors, no scripts are being blocked etc.

Does anyone have any ideas what features in the new version of Mobile Safari could be causing this issue?